# Swift Collection view Horizontal and vertical scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, collectionview

i want to make this Collection view that can scroll horizontal and vertical....but i wanna make something like this

https://giphy.com/gifs/lWshqs2BuvilYuE4Fl/html5

from what i see theres like Collection view and some segmented controll on top of that Collection view...... i mean my only problem is how can i scroll horizontal from anywhere on screen?

like i dont have to scroll from that top segmented control, i can also swipe it from that collection view thing

Any idea how to make this? cause i really dont know if im right or not.....

Thanks

*edit, i cant use library, so i guess i need something that really do it by manual, and for the horizontal scroll i need a dynamic data, i dunno paging controller can use a dynamic data cause as long as i know its static data.

Comment: Use a `UIPageViewController` and a `UICollectionView` for that.

Comment: so i should stack tha page and collection view is that what you meant sir?

Comment: Use a pageViewController for showing different pages (Vouchers, Subscriptions etc.) and  use collectionView too show content of each page.

Comment: ohhh okay so i dont need to use segmented controller for vouchers, etc? i just need page view controller and that collectionview for the content?

Comment: If you are using SwiftUI, you can add an event listener to monitor the user swipe directions, then return corresponding collection view and hide the other one. 
Since there are two collection views, you can use the same or different data sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- take a viewcontroller
- add a view2 give it top constrain and height to 44
- add scrollview and give apropreate constrain (programaticaly or using storyborad choice is your)
- add 3 buttons for voucher , subscription , misson .
- create 3 diffrent ViewControllers for voucher, subscription, misson.
- add 3 viewcontrollers in scrollview

```
// define this variable globally
var previousPageXOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
var pagenumber = 0

// add this in viewdidload
let aViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "voucher") as! voucher

  let bViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "subscription") as! subscription
  
  let cViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "misson") as! misson
  
  let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
  let width = bounds.size.width
  let height = CGFloat(1.0)
  
  let viewControllers = [aViewController, bViewController, cViewController]
  
  self.scrollview!.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(self.totalscreen)*width, height: height)
  
  var idx:Int = 0
  
  for viewController in viewControllers {
      self.addChild(viewController)
      let originX:CGFloat = CGFloat(idx) * width
      viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: originX, y: 0, width: self.scrollview.frame.width, height: self.scrollview.frame.height)
      self.scrollview!.addSubview(viewController.view)
      print("change")
      viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
      idx+=1
  }

// delegate for scrollview 

extension yourVC: UIScrollViewDelegate{
  
  func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      
      previousPageXOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
  }
  
  func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
      
      let targetOffset = targetContentOffset.pointee
      
      if targetOffset.x == previousPageXOffset {
          // page will not change
      } else if targetOffset.x < previousPageXOffset {
          print("left")
          pagenumber = pagenumber - 1
      } else if targetOffset.x > previousPageXOffset {
          print("ryt")
          pagenumber = pagenumber + 1
      }
      
      if pagenumber <= 0 {
          
          //set buttons colors or bottom line in your case if first page is selected
          
      }else if pagenumber == 1{
          //set buttons colors or bottom line in your case if second page is selected
      }else{
          //set buttons colors or bottom line in your case if third page is selected
      }
      print(pagenumber)
      previousPageXOffset = targetOffset.x
      print(previousPageXOffset)
  }
}
```

- function for spacific button(top 3 buttons) click

```
    func scrollToPage(page: Int, animated: Bool) {
        var frame: CGRect = self.scrollview.frame
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
        frame.origin.y = 0
        self.scrollview.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: animated)
    }
```

i hope it will work for you :)

Comment: ahh okay sir i will try you method

Comment: sir i forget, i try your method and it seems like youre method is kinda static, i need a dynamic so i can put my catalog like data like "voucher, subscription, misson", cause  the data is coming from api and i cant use your method, what if theres 10 i need to make the catalog? i cant just make 10 different view controller for each data i want to show

Comment: i understan data came from api but if design of every viewcontroller will different  then you have to create it statically

Comment: oh no sir, the design of every controller is the same, because i use collectionview and every cell is using and xib file that i make, so the design of every controller will be the same

Comment: then you can use this code dynamically , you can call one viewcontroller multyple time and as par count of your viewcontrollers set width for scrollview, in short i just give you method how to do that you have to use it dynamically by your own :)

Comment: and also if you facing problem because of top buttons then you can also set horizontal collectionview in place of buttons

Comment: ahh since you say about horizontal collection view, so basicly i use 2 collection view for horizontal and vertical scroll, so did have have to merge 2 collection view into 1 or is it  just 2 seperate collection view and i just have to control it  seperatly?

Comment: okay.....how do i do that? i mean how i can combine 2 collection view into 1? cause i try to browse it and i cant seems to find it

Comment: visit this answer for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614743/add-uicollectionview-in-uicollectionviewcell

Comment: sir sorry for asking again, but can i just use page controller for your method? it seems its a little bit simpler with a page controller

Comment: no dear i don't mention its page controller , but you can also do it using page controller

Answer (score 2):

add collection view to every single view controller(screen), and apply `Parchment` framework for your required output.

you can get more information about Parchment on :- https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment

**attaching some similar frameworks (select according to your requirement)**

- https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController
- https://github.com/tamanyan/SwiftPageMenu
- https://github.com/EndouMari/TabPageViewController
- https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu

Comment: ahhh okey thanks for this answer, it really helps on how i suppose to do

Comment: but i kinda confused when you said add collection view to every single view....so when i implement that parchment i can still use a collection view right?

Comment: i mean to say create 3 view controller of voucher , subscription and mission and add all in given framwork

Comment: ahhh okayyy i will try that method sir

Comment: sir, sorry i have to undo your  answer, turns out i need to do it manually, i cannot use any library for this, so do you have any idea? im thinking like double layer a collection view for the horizontal and vertical view

Comment: did you try it using scrollview?